# Best way to handle this relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate

System have accounts and it has the terms and conditions to which each account(user) must agree. If terms changed  in the future user will be alerted and based on his choice (agree/not agree) account will remain active or locked.

Now, I want to track list of terms under which user is agreed in the past.

```
Account.cs
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public IList<Terms> Terms {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public bool IsActive {get; set;}
public DateTime AgreedToTerms {get; set;}

Terms.cs
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Text {get; set;}
public DateTime Create {get; set;}
```

I do not have any db tables yet.

Am I on the right track? I need advice or thought how would you handle this relationship?

Thanks

Comment: Will you only have 2 parties to each agreement, or is there a potential for more than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, there are more terms for each user to agree, so this is called a many-to-many relationship (each user has to agree many terms, and one term can be agreed by many users). In these cases a connection entity is needed. In your current situation the connection entity represents the act of agreement, so it would look like this:

```
Account.cs
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public bool IsActive {get; set;}
public IEnumerable<AgreedToTerms> AgreedTerms { get; set; }

Terms.cs
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Text {get; set;}
public DateTime Created {get; set;}
public IEnumerable<AgreedToTerms> AgreedUsers { get; set; }

AgreedToTerms.cs
public Account User { get; set; }
public Terms Terms { get; set; }
public DateTime DateOfAgreement {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make some slight modifications:

Add the following to your Account class:

```
public Dictionary<Guid, bool> AcceptedTOS {get; set;}
```

The `Guid` is the `Id` field in your Terms class, and the `bool` is whether or not they accepted. You can do a simple check if any of them are false to lock the account.

```
if (AcceptedTOS.Any((x)=>x.Value == false))
```

Now, this solution only works if you want to keep everything in c#. If you store the entries in the database, I would advice you use `szelpe`'s answer.

Don't use `IList`, just use `List`. Unless someone can prove me wrong, I don't see any point in using the interface rather than the class.

I would suggest you use `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime`. This gives a higher degree of precision about the date, along with (and this is the important part) the time zone.

You might not want to store the TOS as a string and have it flying around in memory. Depending on your needs, it could get very large.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a bool property to the Terms object that indicates if the terms have been accepted or not. You can still the terms in the same list on the Account class and query the list for unaccepted terms when you need to. If you need to databind to changes to the Terms object within the list, that could be a little more involved, depending on what your front end is written in (WinForms, WPF, etc..).